# Another css margin-top issue... is it really collapsing?

Tags: html, css, margin

In [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BJYLF/), I'm wondering why the blue div does not fully contain the child, since the margin is on the child *inside* the container (i.e. why the space is white on top instead of blue).

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="box"></div>
</div>
```

...

```
#container {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}

#box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 50px;
  background-color: wheat;
}
```

As far as I can tell, **this is not a [collapsing margin](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins) issue,** because only there aren't two margins to collapse; only the child box has a margin.

**Note: I'm looking for the *why*.** I know that making the container a [Block Formatting Context](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-formatting) (demonstrated [here](http://www.css-101.org/block-formatting-contexts/index.php)), fixes the problem (e.g. `overflow:auto`).

Comment: I am confused, what is the issue here?  The wheat box is on top because it is the child.  And it does seem to "fully contain the child".  Could you elaborate on what exactly is wrong with the fiddle, and how you want it to look?

Comment: I think he is wanting the blue container to expand `50px` to contain the margin of the wheat box. Which, if that is the case, use a `padding:50px` on the `container` instead of a `margin:50px` on the `box`.

Comment: I want the blue container to expand to contain the margin of the wheat box, however this isn't a problem-solution question. The question is, **why** does the container not include the margin without making it a BFC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Why**: `Collapsing margins` doesn't mean you need to define a margin for the parent element, the parent element *has* a margin which is automatically calculated by the browser and applied to the element.

Actually, it ***is*** because of the **collapsing margins** of CSS Box model definition:

[CSS 2.1 8.3.1 Collapsing margins](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins)

> In CSS, the adjoining margins of two or more boxes (which might or
>   might not be siblings) can combine to form a single margin. Margins
>   that combine this way are said to collapse, and the resulting combined
>   margin is called a collapsed margin.

From the definition:

> Margins of inline-block boxes do not collapse (not even with their
>   in-flow children).

So *one way* is to change the display of `#box` to `inline-block` to avoid this behavior.

To not touch the `display` type, another way is to use `padding` for the spacing.

Another way is to add `border` of the same color to `#box`. If you do this make sure you also have `box-sizing: border-box;` on `#box` (`-moz-box-sizing: border-box;` for FireFox or Gecko browsers) (Borders prevent margins from collapsing)

**Question asked in comments**: Why adding a `1px` padding prevents margins from collapsing?

From box model definition:

> Adjoining vertical margins collapse.
>
> . . .
>
> (One of the conditions for two margins to be adjoining)
>
> No line boxes, no clearance, *no padding* and no border separate them.

So by definition, if you add `1px` padding then the margins are not adjoining anymore and collapsing doesn't happen.

Comment: Good point (and solutions) but there aren't two margins to collapse in my example. Nothing is being collapsed actually, it's just that the container starts *within* the margin of its child.

Comment: @Raine Collapsing margins doesn't mean you need to define a margin for the parent element, the parent element has a margin which is automatically calculated by the browser and applied to the element.

Comment: @Raine @Arbel is correct, this is a case of collapsing margin, which is easily seen if you increase the top margin to `#box`, which forces the two elments further down the page.  In this case, the 50px top margin of `#box` is collapsing with the 0px margin of `#container`.

Comment: Why is it that adding 1px padding then makes the blue container jump to contain the margin of the box?

Comment: Thanks for sticking with it!

Answer (score 0):

i am afraid its not gonna be an answer that will satisfy you. margins work that way.
margins are allowed to overflow the parent element. they are just meant to create space between the element that margin is on and any other content around it.
if there was some content inside parent element before the #box, it would take the margin inside.
consider this http://jsfiddle.net/BJYLF/2/

```
<div id="hnb">hnb</div>
<div id="container">
hnb
<div id="box">
</div>
</div>
```

in essence, margin is to have space between content not container elements. two adjacent box having content with equal margin will overlap each other's margin for the same reason.

As for overflow, it is working cos auto is not the default.
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp